# VBA Excel 2007 change Macro to search using a range instead of putting the data in the macro

Tags: excel, vba, search, range

I found a macro that suits my needs but it isn't really efficient.  I have a 6,000 row list of addresses I need to ID using data from another spreadsheet.  I've been copying the data I need to search for into the ADDRESSES2SEARCH part of the macro and changing OWNERNAME used to ID them.  I would like to be able to use either a named range or column from the other spreadsheet as the ADDRESSES2SEARCH.  Unfortunately I don't really know enough about VBA to change this macro to do that.  Would anyone be able to help or point me in the right direction?

```
Sub Mark_cells_in_column()
Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim MyArr As Variant
Dim Rng As Range
Dim I As Long
With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
End With
MyArr = Array( ADDRESSES2SEARCH )
With Sheets("Adhoc Boundary Scan").Range("A:A")
.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
For I = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr)
Set Rng = .Find(What:=MyArr(I), _
After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False)
If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
FirstAddress = Rng.Address
Do
Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = OWNERNAME
Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <>      FirstAddress
End If
Next I
End With
With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

What I ended up with using `Autofilter`

```
Sub FilterByCompany()
Dim vOwnerIPs As Variant
Dim wsScan As Worksheet
Dim wsVLANs As Worksheet
Dim rngOwnerIPs As Range
Dim rngScanIPs As Range
Set wsScan = Worksheets("Scan")
Set wsVLANs = Workbooks("VLANs.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rngScanIPs = wsScan.Range("$A$1").CurrentRegion
'search CompanyA
Set rngOwnerIPs = wsVLANS.Range("CompanyArange")
vOwnerIPs = rngOwnerIPs.Value
rngScanIPs.AutoFilter _
    Field:=1, _
    Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(vOwnerIPs), _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues
Intersect(rngScanIPs.EntireRow, wsScan.Range("B:B")).Value = "CompanyA"
'search CompanyB
Set rngOwnerIPs = wsVLANs.Range("CompanyBrange")
vOwnerIPs = rngOwnerIPs.Value
rngScanIPs.AutoFilter _
    Field:=1, _
    Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(vOwnerIPs), _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues
Intersect(rngScanIPs.EntireRow, wsScan.Range("B:B")).Value = "CompanyB"
End Sub
```

Comment: Look up `Autofilter`

Comment: Thanks, `Autofilter` worked like a charm.  Much cleaner and it's pretty easy to modify and add new named ranges to search with in the same module.